# How do I catch error when creating a Mongodb ObjectId using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

`var criteria = Mongoose.Types.ObjectId(payloadData.skillId)`,

when I pass incorrect `Id` following error message is occured.

> Error: Uncaught error: Argument passed in must be a single String of
>   12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters

Comment: What do u actually want to do, please explain in detail

Comment: @tausun, i guess the questions is already clear

Answer (score 5):

The mongo `_id` is 12-byte BSON type `ObjectId`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var id = '1111adda111';
// var id = payloadData.skillId;

console.log(mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)); // false
var cond = mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)

if (cond) {
    // do the required operation
} else {
    console.log('not a valid id');
}
```

Comment: try catch doesn't work, in this case.. validating id before converting it to monodb Id  is the right solution.

Comment: i know that, mine intention was something else the questioner will do with it, but it can also create confusion, so i removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Passing incorrect Mongo `_id` to `Mongoose.Types.ObjectId()` constructor throws `BSONTypeError` which can be caught in a try catch block.

```
import { BSONTypeError } from 'bson';

try {
    const id = Mongoose.Types.ObjectId('xyz');
}
catch {
    if (e instanceof BSONTypeError) {
        console.log('id is invalid');
    }
    else console.log('some other error');
}
```